# Python loop for calculation

Tags: python

I am having some trouble creating logic for loop in python cause Ii am new to python, I do not have any idea of modules. So basically what I need here is a report which will calculate the total available capacity of all the similar hostname in the group Like `Ka` is one group `Kb` is another group `kax-nfs` is nfs share `kbx-nfs` is nfs second group. `kax-clus` is cluster and the second group for cluster is `kbx-clus`.

Each group may have a set of servers, which need be calculated like shown below. For each host, the total line of output is 7 lines. For better understanding, I have skipped the some-content. In some server it is `Total NFS volume size provisioned` or `kbx-hostn` host `Total LUN size provisioned (GB):` but the ``Total available capacity (GB):` remains the same.

All `kbx-hostn` host `Total available capacity (GB):` should be added
All `kbx-hostn` host `Total LUN size provisioned (GB):` should be added

eg:

Total available - Total provisioned = actual available / 1024 = Answer

I am trying to do this in python.

**Required output**

`kbx-hostn 2.1 TB` ----- > is the actual output I need

**Raw_Data**

```
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 18301.64
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 20500.71
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 17251.87
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 19250.54
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 19751.66
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 6000.29
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 20506.90
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 6144.00
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 5376.00
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 512.00
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kax-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-nfshostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 6530.23
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 0
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: kbx-clushostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 202046.45
Total NFS volume size provisioned (GB): 72383.24
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
lo8nv-stmg0001n APP [11:35 AM]
*Netapp Cluster: lax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 13671.27
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 13451.70
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: lax-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 13671.27
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 12451.01
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: hbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 13671.27
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 13300.87
------Some-content------------
*Netapp Cluster: hbx-hostn*
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
------Some-content------------
Total available capacity (GB): 13671.27
------Some-content------------
Total LUN size provisioned (GB): 11200.40
------Some-content------------
```

**Bash script**

```
cat raw_data | sed '/^$/d' | sed '/^Total # of SVMs/d' | sed '/^Total IOPS/d'  | sed '/APP/d' |  sed '/^new/d' | sed '/^Total throughput/d'  |sed '/^\[/d'  | sed 's/\*Netapp Cluster://g' | sed '/^Total physical capacity /d'  | grep -A2  -e  "ax-cluster" -e "bx-cluster" | grep -v -e ^- -e ^$ | awk 'ORS=NR%3?FS:RS' | sort
```

@Cas thanks for your effort & time given for this, but my explanation is bit tricky.

Let's understand it this way here: these below hosts are in a bunch and they together are one cluster, so we need to add Total available capacity & Total LUN size provisioned with that specific output we need subtract & print the actual answer/1024 in TB.

```
*kbx-hostn1* 
*kbx-hostn2*
*kbx-hostn3*
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: @thrig So far I  have tried a bash script, edited the question. the output data is kept in the excel sheet. and then filtered manually.

Comment: The part of your code that starts with `grep` does not seem related to your question at all

Comment: the code is not fully completed it will just show the hostname & the 2 line which is necessary for calculation. rest of the thing are done on excel. that 's the reason i am looking for a script.

Comment: if you try to run the script you will understand.

Comment: @xhienne edited the question with proper explanation, hope my explanation works.

Comment: how important is it that you do this in `python`?  this is a task much better suited to `awk` or `perl`....this is exactly the kind of thing they were written to do.

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is an acceptable language, this is fairly trivial:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $cluster     = '';
my $capacity    = 0;
my $provisioned = 0;

my %C = ();

while(<>) {
  chomp;

  if (m/^\*Netapp Cluster: /) {
    (undef,$cluster) = split(/: /,$_);
    next;
  };

  if (m/^Total available capacity/) {
    (undef,$capacity) = split(/: /,$_);
    next;
  }

  if (m/^Total (LUN|NFS volume) size provisioned/) {
    (undef,$provisioned) = split(/: /,$_);

    $C{$cluster} += $capacity - $provisioned;

    ($cluster,$capacity,$provisioned) = ('',0,0);
    next;
  }
};

for my $cluster (sort keys %C) {
    printf "%s %.1f TB\n", $cluster, $C{$cluster}/1024;
}
```

After saving this script as `summarise-rawdata.pl` and your sample input as `rawdata.txt`, the output is:

```
$ ./summarise-rawdata.pl rawdata.txt
hbx-hostn* 2.8 TB
kax-hostn* 56.2 TB
kax-nfshostn* 19.0 TB
kbx-clushostn* 126.6 TB
kbx-hostn* 45.4 TB
kbx-nfshostn* 20.3 TB
lax-hostn* 1.4 TB
```

Here's an `awk` version:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^\*Netapp Cluster: / { cluster=$NF };

/^Total available capacity/ { capacity=$NF };

/^Total (LUN|NFS volume) size provisioned/ {
  C[cluster] += capacity - $NF;

  cluster=capacity="";
};

END {
  for (cluster in C) {
    printf "%s %.1f TB\n", cluster, C[cluster] / 1024;
  };
}
```

The output is the same in both `awk` and `perl` versions, except that the `awk` output isn't sorted, while the `perl` output is.

It's possible to sort an associative array by index in `awk` but it's much easier to just pipe the output through `sort` if sorting is required.

Comment: Depending on the actual contents of the `---Some-content---` lines, this could be sped up and simplified a little with something like `next unless (m/^(\*Netapp Cluster|Total available|Lun size provisioned)/);` immediately before the `chomp` line to just skip over "un-interesting" lines.

Comment: An `awk` version of this would be very similar, but less verbose (probably half as many code lines).

Comment: The awk version is 1/3rd the number of code lines (10 vs 3).  For trivial jobs like this, awk is better.   For more complex jobs, perl is worth considering.

Comment: This is little tricky to explain, I will explain it hereagain, The calculation will be like this, all the host with same name should be added and then calculated. eg. All hostname in `kbx-hostn`, `kax-hostn`, `kbx-nfshostn`, `kax-nfshostn`, `kbx-clushostn`, `lax-hostn` & `hbx-hostn` are bunch of host. So they need to be added and then the output should be shown.

Comment: so you want each **unique** "Netapp Cluster" totalled, and then printed at the end.  that's not difficult.  i'll post an update in a few minutes.

Comment: Could you check the question, I have tried to explain. as per the output there are several host with the same name `kbx-hostn1`. we need to add those data and then subtract it.

Comment: your question makes even less sense now than it did before.  what is it that you actually want?   I suggest you try taking either my perl script or my awk script and trying to adapt them to do whatever it is that you want.  they're fairly simple, and easy to understand.  they both implement the same algorithm.  they're both easy to modify.   if you prefer python, the same algorithm can be implemented in python, and then modified to suit your requirements.